# Can I just run Symfony project without the use of composer or even installing Symfony in XAMPP?

Tags: php, windows, symfony, xampp, composer-php

I think this sounds ridiculous, but I really need help on this one.

Our supervisor wants us to create a Symfony project from scratch with

User login

User Panel

User Role

But the problem is, we can't install composer and Symfony in XAMPP because of

```
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I search and tried to fix it by locating the cacert.pem which was the initial recommendations on how to fix that error but still no luck. I think it's something to do with the security restrictions in our machine because we're working in a company.

Is there anyway that I could start a Symfony project from scratch without installing composer and Symfony installer? or can I just copy an existing Symfony project, like Symfony-demo and paste it in my /xampp/htdocs/ folder?

I'm using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.9 in Windows 7 Pro as my OS.

Comment: So you've edited your XAMPP php.ini file to include `curl.cainfo = "C:\path\to\cacert.pem"` in it already, and you still get that error?

Comment: Symfony is far easier to maintain with Composer and is required for 3.3 or newer versions for the autoloader. The error generally means server's CA is very old (seeing as it is Windows 7 it is likely), OpenSSL is disabled in php, or an invalid path to the CA file. And would more than likely mean other errors for different services in PHP. So would suggest to fix that error. Ensure `extension=php_openssl.dll` is uncommented in your php.ini file. Also please link to a pastebin of your `php.exe -i`, removing any confidential information.

Comment: To add-on to Alvin's comment, add `openssl.cafile="C:\path\to\ca-bundle.cr"` to your `php.ini`. Be sure to restart apache after making changes. Also please provide the method(s) you used to install composer. I can walk you through the manual composer configuration, but would like to know if you've attempted it before answering.

Comment: Yup! I tried it already base from the sources I've searches. I followed every step in installing composer and Symfony. But still got the same error. I asked our supervisor about that error and he said it conflicts with the firewall or something like that. I tried installing composer and Symfony in my own machine and it went well without that error.

Comment: Sounds like your supervisor should fix the underlying issue at hand

Comment: But to answer your original question, yes you can install a Symfony project on another machine and then copy the resulting files over and it should work.  Same principle as ftp'ing an app to a shared host with no ssh access.

Comment: @Cerad, seriously? Well if that's the case, then maybe I'm just gonna create on my machine then copy it to our companies localhost. Is that alright?

Comment: Yep.  That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but why I can't just copy the Symfony-demo application and paste it in our companies xampp/htdocs folder? It still won't run without Composer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known problem on Windows 7 that I have run into a few times with composer. You have to install the Mozilla certificate manually from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html. I thtink you should be able to install the pem-file by double clicking and then pressing a button, but if not you can find elaborate install instructions in the [Microsoft KnowledgeBase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754489(v=ws.11).aspx).

edit: In the composer repository I found [this ticket](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3950) that seems to relate to this that might help you.